# How to get 100 scores in google pagespeed insights use Angular Cli 9?

Tags: angular, pagespeed-insights

Why from box Angular Cli 9 get 95 scores, and Svelte 100 scores?

What should I do, so that get 100 scores with angular cli?

It's possible?

Comment: Run your site and see what it says you can improve on.

Comment: fcp and lcp content.

Comment: fcp fix : add loader in index.html.

Comment: what to do with lcp?